# FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator ckeditor full?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, bundle

Is it somehow possible to change the standard ckeditor in frozennodes laravel bundle Administrator with the full featured one? I downloaded the full ckeditor und replaced the old ckeditor-directory with the extraced files of the full version but nothing happens. Any tipps here?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: in the first picture you see the current one and beneath that the expected one, see also here http://ckeditor.com/demo#full. I updated all files but nothing happens..

[image: currently it is like that]
[image: expected one]

Comment: What do you mean by full version? Some icons in the toolbar is missing? Can you show us the screenshot of what you have now and what you are expecting?

Comment: Does your ckeditor's config.js look something like this? https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/blob/full/stable/config.js or like this https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/blob/standard/stable/config.js ?

Comment: It looks like the first one, but is is nowhere included, only the ckeditor.js file

Answer (score 0):

Okay found it out on my own!
Download the full featured one, copy it to the public directory of your laravel application in a folder named ckeditor.
After that search for the file viewComposers.php in the frozennode vendor folder and in that the phrase "ckeditor". You will see that there is a js declaration of the needed ckeditor.js file.
Just change the value to asset('ckeditor/ckeditor.js').
And there you go :-).